# Django: How to redirect or disconnect the user when he came back to the previous page or coming back to the login page

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I thank you in advance for any help you could give to me about this question.

I would like the user to be redirect automatically to another page in my Django web application in the case he click on the button in order to coming back to the last page, or when he came back to the login page again I would like to disconnect it and when he still logged and he try to access to the register page, I would to disconnect it or redirect to another page from my website.

I have already tried LoginMixin and redirect but nothing. 
when I am already logged and backing to the previous page I mean the login page I am still logged and I am have the login page even when I am already logged, the same I can go back to the register page but I am already logged.

I am using Django 2.1.7 the latest version.
So help any help will be appreciated.

Thank you again.

Here is my code the correct one. maybe he can help anyone else.

```
def login(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('index')

    else:

        if request.method == 'POST':
            email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']


def get_next_url():
                #request = self.request
                next_ = request.GET.get('next')
                next_post = request.POST.get('next')
                redirect_path = next_ or next_post or None
                if is_safe_url(redirect_path, request.get_host()):
                    return redirect_path
                return 'user-home'
            # def get_client_ip(request):
            #     x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
            #     if x_forwarded_for:
            #         ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
            #     else:
            #         ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
            #     return ip



def get_ip_address_from_request(request):      
""" Makes the best attempt to get the client's real IP or return the loopback """
                PRIVATE_IPS_PREFIX = ('10.', '172.', '192.', '127.')
                ip_address = ''
                x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', '')
                if x_forwarded_for and ',' not in x_forwarded_for:
                    if not x_forwarded_for.startswith(PRIVATE_IPS_PREFIX) and is_valid_ip(x_forwarded_for):
                        ip_address = x_forwarded_for.strip()
                else:
                    ips = [ip.strip() for ip in x_forwarded_for.split(',')]
                    for ip in ips:
                        if ip.startswith(PRIVATE_IPS_PREFIX):
                            continue
                        elif not is_valid_ip(ip):
                            continue
                        else:
                            ip_address = ip
                            break
                if not ip_address:
                    x_real_ip = request.META.get('HTTP_X_REAL_IP', '')
                    if x_real_ip:
                        if not x_real_ip.startswith(PRIVATE_IPS_PREFIX) and is_valid_ip(x_real_ip):
                            ip_address = x_real_ip.strip()
                if not ip_address:
                    remote_addr = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR', '')
                    if remote_addr:
                        if not remote_addr.startswith(PRIVATE_IPS_PREFIX) and is_valid_ip(remote_addr):
                            ip_address = remote_addr.strip()
                if not ip_address:
                    ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
                    ip_address = ip
                return ip_address

            try:
                ip = get_ip_address_from_request(request)
                user = User.objects.get(email=email)
                if user.check_password(password) and user.is_active:
                    email = user.email
                    user = auth.authenticate(email=email, password=password)
                    auth.login(request, user)
                    alert_connection = User.objects.filter(connection_info=True)

                    if alert_connection:
                        base_url = getattr(settings, 'BASE_URL', 'http://www.dram-access.com')
                        context = {
                            'base_url': base_url,
                            'ip': ip,
                            'email': request.user.email,
                            'first_name': request.user.first_name,
                            'last_name': request.user.last_name
                            }
                        txt_ = get_template("accounts/emails/send_just_logged.txt").render(context)
                        html_ = get_template("accounts/emails/send_just_logged.html").render(context)
                        subject = 'New connection on your DreamAccess account'
                        from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
                        recipient_list = [request.user.email] 
                        send_mail(
                            subject,
                            message=txt_,
                            from_email=from_email,
                            recipient_list=recipient_list,
                            html_message = html_,
                            fail_silently=False,
                        )

                    messages.success(request, 'You are now logged in on DreamAccess')
                    next_path = get_next_url()
                    return redirect(next_path)

                elif user.check_password(password):
                    qs = User.objects.filter(email=email)
                    if qs.exists():
                        #user email registered check active
                        not_active = qs.filter(is_active=False).exists()
                        confirm_email = EmailActivation.objects.filter(email=email, activated=False, forced_expired=False)
                        #is_confirmable = confirm_email.confirmable().exists()
                        if confirm_email and not_active:
                            return redirect('account-user-inactive')
                        elif not_active:
                            return redirect("send-reactivation-message")
                else:
                    messages.error(request, "Your password is invalid")
                    return redirect('login')
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                messages.error(request, "This username and password doesn't exist on DreamAccess")
                return redirect('login')
        else:
            return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')`
```

My Register page code:

```
def register(request):

if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect('index')
else:
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
    context = {
        'form': form
        }
    if form.is_valid():
        #form.save()

        first_name = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        last_name = form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        country = form.cleaned_data.get('country')
        types = form.cleaned_data.get('types')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        password2 = form.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        phone = form.cleaned_data.get('phone')
        profile_pic = form.cleaned_data.get('profile_pic')

        new_user = User.objects.create_user(first_name, last_name, username, email, country, types, password, phone, profile_pic)

    else:
        return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide your code, if you have any. On the signup page view, your code should look like this:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    # HttpResponseRedirect('/redirectToNonRegisterPageURL/')
    ...
else:
    # Load Sign Up Form
    ...
```

Comment: Oh thank you very @user2719875, I have already did the same but with bracket like this if request.user.is_authenticated(): so without the bracket it worked perfectly and I guest I should do the same for the register. Thank very  much for your quick response, god bless you

Comment: @Michael Can you update your question to include your code / views?

Comment: I did it @user2719875

Comment: he doesn't worked for the register page, I still get the register page when I go back to the url page even when I am logged. Any help will be welcome.